# Extract class name with styled-components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm using a UI library that requires you to pass the class name in a `skin` prop in order to customise the internals of a component. Something like:

```
import styles from './ProfileInfoSkins.css';

...

<ProfileInfo skin={{ headline: styles.headline }}
```

I'm wondering if there is any way to do that by using styled-components and avoid having to create a separate css file.

Comment: Is that actually a CSS file? or is it an exported style object?

Answer (score 1):

[.attrs](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#attrs)

> This is a chainable method that attaches some props to a styled
>   component. The first and only argument is an object that will be
>   merged into the rest of the component's props.

[Attaching additional props](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#attaching-additional-props)

```
const StyledProfileInfo = styled(ProfileInfo).attrs(
  props => ({
    skin: {
      headline: { /* headline style object */ },
      // add whatever other skin object properties needed
    },
  }), 
);
```